# Populate Object Array to Mongoose through API

Tags: node.js, api, express, post, mongoose

I'm currently running into issues posting my data with array through the API using Mongoose.

Currently this data is showing in my console:

```
taskName: 'name',
  word: 'word2',
  wordDesc: 'description',
  tag: [ { text: 'word0' }, { text: 'word1' }, { text: 'word2' } ] }
```

I need the tag array to be pushed to the database with seperate values, so I can post/target each individual word into HTML for later usage.

Currently I add the whole array into my database collection, which is giving me this data on my database:

```
"word": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
```

How do I loop through each item in my array and insert it individually to the database?

**API code**

```
 router.post('/task', function (req,res) {
            var task = req.body.tag;
            var taskDesc = req.body.wordDesc;
            var taskName = req.body.taskName;
            console.log(req.body);
            var newTask = new Task ({
                tags:[{word:task}],
                wordDesc: taskDesc,
                taskName: taskName 
            });


            newTask.save(function(err){
                if (err) {
                    return res.send(err);
                }
                return res.json(newTask);
            });
        });
```

**MongoDB Schema**

```
var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    tags: [{
         word        : {type: String, default: ""}
    }],

    wordDesc    : {type: String, default: ""},
    taskName    : {type: String, default: ""}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem you can do it like this:

```
...
  var newTask = new Task();
  newTask.wordDesc = taskDesc;
  newTask.taskName = taskName;

  wordTasks.forEach(word=>{
     newTask.tags.push(word);
  });

  newTask.save(function(err){
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

We ended up drawing some inspiration from your example and the code ended up looking like this and functions as we wanted it:

```
var word = req.body.tag;
        var taskDesc = req.body.wordDesc;
        var taskName = req.body.taskName;
        console.log(req.body);

        var newTask = new Task();          
             newTask.taskName = taskName;
             newTask.wordDesc = taskDesc;
          for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
             console.log(word[i].text);
             newTask.tags.push(word[i]);
                }
```